# Grape Molasses - Kosher Without Hashgachah?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

Per my CRC Kosher app, "molasses" is kosher without a hashgachah needed. What about grape molasses though?

Per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petimezi, grape must is used to make it, so I'd assume it would need a hashgachah, no?

Comment: How is this different from grape juice?

Comment: @DoubleAA Isn't this off topic? Sounds like it's asking for a psak.

Comment: I would suggest that you contact the CRC

Comment: @YaacovDeane I doesn't sound that way to me, but obviously this's more of a judgement call than anything and there's a spectrum with plenty of gray.

Comment: franny 8102, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for bringing your question here!

Answer (score 3):

Email from the CRC:

> Rabbi Fishbane showed me your question about grape molasses and asked me to respond.
>
> You are correct that molasses made from grape would require certification.  I don’t think this is a very common item, and that’s why we didn’t note that it is an exception, but I will instruct our people to add that detail to the entry for “molasses”.
>
> Thank you for pointing this out to us
>
> Rabbi Dovid Cohen
>
> Chicago Rabbinical Council

Comment: efremdan1, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for reaching out and reporting back! I look forward to seeing you around.